# I just installed Gangstar New Orleans from Microsoft Store but it's loading forever!

Tags: gangstar-new-orleans

When I open the game, I see the logo of Gameloft in the middle of a black screen and the word "loading" is flashing in the lower right corner and that's it. The game never started.

I thought it's downloading a big file but I can tell that the internet connection is not used by opening the task manager.

I waited for so long but the game isn't starting. Would you help me please?

**My specs:**

CPU: Core2Due 2.33 GHz

RAM: 3 GB

Nvidia GeForce 710 GT

Windows 10

**Edit:** I updated windows 10 to the latest version but the same thing happens!

**Edit 2:** I tried to open it few days later after updating the windows and now it **works**. IDK how. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: `I waited for so long but the game isn't starting` -- what is "so long"? 30 seconds? 5 minutes? 6 hours?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I updated Windows 10 to the latest version (current version in the market). First time loading takes time, so patience is important. If it takes too long like 15 minutes, you may try to close the game and reopen it. I actually closed the game and opened it again a few days later since I was occupied. There could have been an issue with the server at that day. The game shouldn't take a long time to start each time. It just takes time for the first launch only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is with your hardware not being strong enough to run this easily. A quick google search shows that Windows 10 requires 1GB of RAM, and Gangstar New Orleans requires 2GB of RAM. At this point you have already hit your total RAM and if you have anything else running (like the task manager) the computer will be forced to be what is known as "memory swapping." This is a slow process that will kill run speeds and loading times. The game also recommends an 8-core processor, and the one you specified is a 2-core processor. Again, this will cause slowdowns, if the game is able to run at all.

You may get lucky and be able to run this game, but you should expect very long loading times (up to several minutes for each load) and possible lag spikes even in offline mode. Best way to solve this issue would be to upgrade your computer or buy a better one.